# Python: concatenating text files

Tags: python

Using Python, I'm seeking to iteratively combine two set of txt files to create a third set of txt files.

I have a directory of txt files in two categories:

1. `text_[number].txt` (eg: `text_0.txt`, `text_1.txt`, `text_2.txt`....`text_20.txt`)
2. `comments_[number].txt` (eg: `comments_0.txt`, `comments_1.txt`, `comments_2.txt`...`comments_20.txt`).

I'd like to iteratively combine the `text_[number]` files with the matching `comments_[number]` files into a new file category `feedback_[number].txt`. The script would combine `text_0.txt` and `comments_0.txt` into `feedback_0.txt`, and continue through each pair in the directory. The number of `text` and `comments` files will always match, but the total number of `text` and `comment` files is variable depending on preceding scripts.

I can combine two pairs using the code below with a list of file pairs:

```
filenames = ['text_0.txt', 'comments_0.txt']

with open("feedback_0.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            contents = infile.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
```

However, I'm uncertain how to structure iteration for the rest of the files. I'm also curious how to generate lists from the contents of the file directory. Any advice or assistance on moving forward is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the files nes going to be alternate, i.e is it always in text_n followed by comments_n

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant but...

```
length = 10
txt = [f"text_{n}.txt" for n in range(length)]
com = [f"comments_{n}.txt" for n in range(length)]
feed = [f"feedback_{n}.txt" for n in range(length)]

for f, t, c in zip(feed, txt, com):
    with open(f, "w") as outfile:
        with open(t) as infile1:
            contents = infile1.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
        with open(c) as infile2:
            contents = infile2.read()
            outfile.write(contents)
```

Comment: Why generate all the names beforehand? That is completely unnecessary...

Comment: What if there are more thsn 10 files

Comment: Of course, 10 was just a random number but you clearly choose how many you have.  And generating the names beforehand ensures you only use the files you intend to in case the folder is a bit polluted.

Comment: Note that `txt`, `com`, and `feed` could all be generators, which would give you the readability without the cost of storing the names in memory unnecessarily.

Comment: I wouldn't open the files in text mode, though, as that means you'll have to decode and re-encode each line unnecessarily. Just read in the raw bytes and write them back (which is what `cat` does in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

It would be far simpler (and possibly faster) to just fork a `cat` process:

```
import subprocess


n = ... # number of files
for i in range(n):
    with open(f'feedback_{i}.txt', 'w') as f:
        subprocess.run(['cat', 'text_{i}.txt', 'comments_{i}.txt'], stdout=f)
```

Or, if you already have lists of the file names:

```
for text, comment, feedback in zip(text_files, comment_files, feedback_files):
    with open(feedback, 'w') as f:
        subprocess.run(['cat', text, comment], stdout=f)
```

Unless these are all *extremely* small files, the cost of reading and writing the bytes will outweigh the cost of forking a new process for each pair.

Comment: I like considering launching a native program like `cat` to this more efficiently, but I think it makes the solution unnecessarily non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be to just iterate from 1 onwards, stopping at the first missing file. This works assuming that your files are numbered in increasing order and with no gaps (e.g. you have 1, 2, 3 and not 1, 3).

```py
import os
from itertools import count

for i in count(1):
    t = f'text_{i}.txt'
    c = f'comments_{i}.txt'

    if not os.path.isfile(t) or not os.path.isfile(c):
        break

    with open(f'feedback_{i}.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(open(t, 'rb').read())
        outfile.write(open(c, 'rb').read())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, but I don't seem to see any solution that's both beginner-friendly and takes into account the structure of the files you described.

You can iterate through the files, and for every `text_[num].txt`, fetch the corresponding `comments_[num].txt` and write to `feedback_[num].txt` as shown below. There's no need to add any counters or make any other assumptions about the files that might not always be true:

```py
import os

srcpath = 'path/to/files'

for f in os.listdir(srcpath):
    if f.startswith('text'):
        index = f[5:-4] # extract the [num] part

        # Build the paths to text, comment, feedback files
        txt_path = os.path.join(srcpath, f)
        cmnt_path = os.path.join(srcpath, f'comments_{index}.txt')
        fb_path = os.path.join(srcpath, f'feedback_{index}.txt')

        # write to output – reading in in byte mode following chepner's advice
        with open(fb_path, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(open(txt_path, 'rb').read())
            outfile.write(open(cmnt_path, 'rb').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
filenames = ['text_0.txt', 'comments_0.txt','text_1.txt', 'comments_1.txt','text_2.txt', 'comments_2.txt','text_3.txt', 'comments_3.txt']
for i,j in enumerate (zip(filenames[::2],filenames[1::2])):
    with open(f'feedback_{i}','a+') as file:
        for k in j:
        with open(k,'r') as f:
                files=f.read()
                file.write(files)
```

I have taken a list here. Instead, you can do

```
import os
filenames=os.listdir('path/to/folder')
```